# How do I get switch() to loop multiple times in C?

Tags: c

I have created this fruit machine game. However I would like to loop the output several times before printing a final output that is then scored. To simulate the moving nature of a real slot machine. When I try and loop my switch() statements no output is produced. How would I go about doing this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int main ()
{
  int firstReel, secondReel, thirdReel, loop;

  // Generating three random numbers
  srand(time(NULL));
  int rndOne = rand () %4;
  int rndTwo = rand () %4;
  int rndThree = rand () %4;

  // Assigning random numbers to clearer var names
  firstReel = rndOne;
  secondReel = rndTwo;
  thirdReel = rndThree;

  // Switch statements for each reel
  switch(firstReel){
    case 0:
      printf("Bell ");
      break;
    case 1:
      printf("Cherry ");
      break;
    case 2:
      printf("Orange ");
      break;
    case 3:
      printf("Horseshoe ");
      break;
  }

  switch(secondReel){
    case 0:
      printf("Bell ");
      break;
    case 1:
      printf("Cherry ");
      break;
    case 2:      
      printf("Orange ");
      break;
    case 3:
      printf("Horseshoe ");
      break;
  }

  switch(thirdReel){
    case 0:
      printf("Bell\n");
      break;
    case 1:
      printf("Cherry\n");
      break;
    case 2:
      printf("Orange\n");
      break;
    case 3:
      printf("Horseshoe\n");
      break;
  }
  // Win/lose conditions
  if (firstReel == secondReel || firstReel == thirdReel || secondReel == thirdReel)
    printf("Congratulations! You win!\n");
  else
  {
  printf("Sorry, you lose. Play again? (Y/N)\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: Umm, put it in some sort of for/while loop?

Comment: Use a function and call it three times with each reel as an input.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a loop as shown below :
Here I am running the loop for some x number of times.You can run the loop for any number of times you wish to.

```
 int main ()
    {
      int firstReel;
      int i=0;
      // Generating three random numbers
      srand(time(NULL));

      // Assigning random numbers to clearer var names


    while(i<7)
    {
        firstReel = rand () %4;
      // Switch statements for each reel
      switch(firstReel){
        case 0:
          printf("Bell ");
          break;
        case 1:
          printf("Cherry ");
          break;
        case 2:
          printf("Orange ");
          break;
        case 3:
          printf("Horseshoe ");
          break;
      }
      i++;

    }
    }
```

Comment: YOu need to change the test at the end too (or remove it) since it assumes three separate reels still

Comment: @Paul Agree just added some condition instead of it

Answer (score 0):

use some sort of counter/ looping statement

```
int i=0;
while(i< 10){

       //Your switch statements
 i++;

 }
```

As a better programming practice please do include default case/scenario too when the switch input  doesn't satisfy any of the cases.. helps in keeping the code structured and avoids any confusion also showing that other values have been taken care of. For ex:

```
 default: 
         printf("Invalid value entered");
         break;
```

Comment: You need to increment `i`. And if you're doing that, why not a `for` loop?

Comment: Yes,thanks had accidentally skipped that statement.. you can use for loop too... but I just used while here

Answer (score 0):

This will show the reels spinning and slowing to the final pattern (in a console).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define SYMBOLS     4
#define REELS       3
#define SPINS       20

char *symbol [SYMBOLS] = {"   Bell   ", "  Cherry  ", "  Orange  ", "Horseshoe "};
int reel [REELS];

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int s, r, elap, tix, counts;

    srand ((unsigned)time(NULL));
    for (s=SPINS; s>0; s--) {
        printf ("\r");
        for (r=0; r<REELS; r++) {
            reel [r] = rand() % SYMBOLS;
            printf ("%s", symbol [reel [r]]);
        }
        tix = clock();
        counts = CLOCKS_PER_SEC / s;
        do {
            elap = clock() - tix;
        }
        while (elap < counts);
    }

    printf ("\n");
    for (r=1; r<REELS; r++)
        if (reel [r] != reel [r-1])
            break;
    if (r < REELS)
        printf ("You lost!\n");
    else
        printf ("You won!\n");
    return 0;
}
```